# What to use instead of XDoclet in Eclipse for Java EE development?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, xdoclet

My PC's operating system is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

I have an old enterprise application which is using XDoclet 1.2.3 in Eclipse. The app uses EJB 2.1 and is deployed on JBoss 4.3.2 server.

What to use instead of XDoclet in Eclipse for Java EE development?

Thanks

Comment: Xdoclet is a dead tool since Java 5, it was substituted by annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace XDoclet with the annotations, this is the most popular way now. Check this [Now that we have annotations in java, is xdoclet legacy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611473/now-that-we-have-annotations-in-java-is-xdoclet-legacy)